# Editing the UIPickerView

Tags: swift3, uipickerview

I have successfully performed UIPickerView. The row gets selected from UIPickerView and gets passed to textField. After this, I want to choose options again. But when I tap the pickerView, it doesn't get popped up.I can only choose once but I need it to perform as many times as user wants.I couldn't find the solution for Swift3. Please help me sort out this in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check this func, insted of textField You have to Unhide PickerView

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == self.textField {
        //self.textField.isHidden = false
        self.pickerView.isHidden = false
        textField.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Thank U Sir :)  @ Ronak